# OpenCV only accepts my path string in PyCharm

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pycharm, tesseract, python-tesseract

When I try to run my code in PyCharm, it exits with code 0, and gives the desired output, but when I try to run it in VS Code it gives the following error:

`File "c:\Users\1\Desktop\ImagetoText\ITT2.py", line 21, in <module> img = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB) cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.1) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-kh7iq4w7\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'`

How it is possible that the same code runs without errors or warnings relating to this line in PyCharm while not working in VS Code or directly in W10 is alien to my understanding.

Note: I have tried tweaking the path but to no avail.

Code:

```
from glob import glob
from io import BytesIO
import pytesseract
import cv2 as cv
from tkinter import *
import pyperclip
import os

presentItem = ImageGrab.grabclipboard()

with BytesIO() as f:
    presentItem.save(f, format='PNG')
    presentItem.save('tempITT' + '.png', 'PNG')


pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:\\Users\\1\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'
img = cv.imread(r"C:\Users\1\Desktop\ImagetoText\tempITT.png")
img = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
imgtext = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)

pyperclip.copy(imgtext)

os.remove(r"C:\Users\1\Desktop\ImagetoText\tempITT.png")
```

Comment: Firts check if you really have this image. `imread` doesn't show error when it can't find image but it returns `None` and later you have `cv.cvtColor(None, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)` which gives error with text `!_src.empty()`

Comment: `presentItem.save(...)` may save image in local folder, not in `C:\Users\1\Desktop\ImagetoText` and later `imread('C:\Users\1\Desktop\ImagetoText\..')` may not find it. Better use full path in all places `presentItem.save(r'C:\Users\1\Desktop\ImagetoText\tempITT.png')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firts check if you really have this image.

```
C:\Users\1\Desktop\ImagetoText\tempITT.png
```

`imread` doesn't show error when it can't find image but it returns `None` and later code run `cv.cvtColor(None, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)` which gives error with text `!_src.empty()`

I think all your problem starts with `presentItem.save(...)` because you use filename without full path - so it may save it in local folder, not in `C:\Users\1\Desktop\ImagetoText`, and later `imread(r'C:\Users\1\Desktop\ImagetoText\...`) can't find it.

You should use full path in all functions

```
presentItem.save(r'C:\Users\1\Desktop\ImagetoText\tempITT.png', 'PNG')
```

---

**BTW:**

When you have code `C:\Users\1\Desktop\ImagetoText` and you run it from this folder

```
 cd C:\Users\1\Desktop\ImagetoText
 python script.py
```

then `presentItem.save("tempITT.png")` saves file in this folder `C:\Users\1\Desktop\ImagetoText` and you have `C:\Users\1\Desktop\ImagetoText\tempITT.png`,

but if you run code for other folder

```
 cd other folder 
 python C:\Users\1\Desktop\ImagetoText\script.py
```

then `presentItem.save("tempITT.png")` saves file in other foler you have `C:\other folder\tempITT.png`

And this can happend in your situation. Different tools may runs it in different way and later `presentItem.save(` may save file in different folder - and you should use full path in `presentItem.save()`

Folder in which code is executed is called `Current Working Directory` and you can see it using `print( os.getcwd() )`